# What happened to the Node classes in V1.8.0?

Tags: libgdx, path-finding, gdx-ai

In `V1.7.0` I was able to extend from the Node interfaces that came with `gdx-ai` but in `V1.8.0` they do not exist? Double question:

- Why?
- How can I implement my own Node from scratch? I mean/guess, the other classes need core functionality from the nodes that previously came from the supplied interfaces like `IndexedNode`, `TiledNode`, etc.

I specifically need this for the Hierarchical pathfinding implementation. I can roll back to `V1.7.0` but if the latest version is not broken I rather use that of course.